# Convert GB2312 to UTF-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, gb2312

I have a text file that contains localized language strings that is currently encoded in GB2312 (simplified Chinese), but all of my other language files are in UTF-8. I am finding it very difficult to work with this file, as none of my text editors will work properly with it and keep corrupting it. Are there any tools to convert this to UTF-8, and are there any downsides to doing this? Would it be better to just keep it as GB2312 and use a different editor (if so, can you recommend one)?

**Update:** I'm using Windows XP (English install).

**Update #2:** I've tried using Notepad++ and Notepad2 to edit the GB2312 files, but both are unable to read the files and corrupt them.

Comment: Which environment? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Sorry, it's in Windows XP (English install).

Comment: You could try writing a quick/small java utility that reads the file into a String as GB2312 and then writes it back out as UTF-8. That should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this [online service](http://www.iconv.org/) that uses the Open Source `iconv` utility.
You can also install [Charco](http://www.marblesoftware.com/Charco.html),  a command-line version of it on your machine.

For `GB2312`, you can use `CP936` as the encoding.

If you are a .Net developer you can make a small tool that does just that.
I've struggled with this as well and found that it was actually simple to solve from a programmatic point of view.

All you need is something like this (I tested it and it works):

**In C#**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string infile = args[0];
    string outfile = args[1];

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(infile, Encoding.GetEncoding(936))) {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outfile, false, Encoding.UTF8)) {
            sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sw.Close();
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

**In VB.Net**

```
Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim infile As String = args(0)
    Dim outfile As String = args(1)
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(infile, Encoding.GetEncoding(936))
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(outfile, false, Encoding.UTF8)
    sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd)
    sw.Close
    sr.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know GB2312 maps to CP936? Where can I find a table that relates every single character set to a corresponding codepage to be able to support any language?

Answer (score 5):

I might be thinking a bit too simple here, but if it's just this one plain text file, you could try the following:

1. Replace all `&` by `&amp;`, all `<` by `&lt;` and all `>` by `&gt;` (to be on the safe side)
2. Prepend the following to the text file:

   `<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" /></head><body><pre>`
3. Open the file in your favorite browser
4. Select and copy all text
5. Paste it in Notepad and save as UTF-8.

You'd be done with this before you could have written any code to do the conversion or downloaded any programs that would do the conversion for you.

Of course, I'm not a hundred percent sure this'll work, and your browser would need the correct fonts and everything, but considering you're working with these kinds of files I'm assuming you already have those.

Answer (score 2):

GB 2312 is mostly compatible with GB 18030, so any tool able to deal with the latter should treat GB 2312 correctly as well.  There are many tools for converting GB 18030 to UTF-8 (or some other Unicode encoding form), but I can't recommend any specific one for Windows, because I work on Unix.  If you're wanting to write a bit of code, the iconv library, or [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/), springs to mind: you'll find all the conversion data readily available in these libraries.

Conversion from GB 2312 to UTF-8 is completely safe and lossless, you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

If there is command line tool `iconv` in your OS, you can achieve this by running the **one-line** scirpt:

```bash
# From GB18030
iconv -f gb18030 -t utf8 -o output.txt input.txt

# From GB2313
iconv -f gb2313 -t utf8 -o output.txt input.txt
```

Check whether your OS have `iconv`:

```bash
$ iconv --version
iconv (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u3) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree on the currently chosen answer in that "found that it was actually simple to solve from a programmatic point of view", especially when your source file contains sensitive information that you do not want to expose to an unknown 3rd-party online service.

And, nowadays Python is available out-of-box in most Linux environment, and also easy to install on a Windows environment (easier than installing C# stack, IMHO). So, without further ado, this is the 2-liner Python script that can convert GB2312 to UTF8. I tested it, it works.

```py
# Usage: python this_script.py your_input.txt your_output.txt
import io, sys
io.open(sys.argv[2], "w", encoding="utf-8").write(io.open(sys.argv[1], encoding="gb2312").read())
```