# Azure Blob Storage Upload - Special Characters uploading as Question marks ??.jpg

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have Chinese/Mandarin characters in a file that I'm uploading to Azure blob, e.g. 此测试.jpg

When I drag and drop this file to Azure via Azure Explorer (as a test to make sure the environment can handle it) - then the file uploads perfectly with the filename :  此测试.jpg   (when I use a different Azure Explorer from Redgate then it gets uploaded as ????.jpg)

I follow the normal boilerplate code to upload

```
 Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"))
 Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
 Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename)
  blockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(FileBytes, 0, FileBytes.Length)
```

, but it gets uploaded as `????.jpg`

How can I upload the file to blob to have the correct (special character) filename? I saw php examples but nothing related to .net which I could apply

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem related to your upload code.
There are [different types of Chinese character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding) and unfortunately only unicode would play nicely with .Net

I would grab the file name (Likely it's encoded in GB since it's simplified chinese), convert it to unicode follow the [suggestions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379191/convert-gb2312-to-utf-8)

Unicode chinese is expected to work, but they are still considered to be special character. If it still gives you problem, you will probly need to wrap in [Base64 encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) or [URLencoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) **in addition to unicode**. These two encoding method would not work with GB or Big5.